# Can the legal owner of a vehicle cancel a change of keeper request?

Tags: united-kingdom, car, car-insurance

I am the legal owner of a car. I don't posses a Full UK Licence (I have a Provisional) so whilst I was waiting for my test I transferred the car to a friend (V5) which made him the registered keeper. We have still not received the V5 back to say the change has been dealt with.

We now want to transfer the car back as my friend has ran into unexpected problems and I wish to get learners insurance on the car. -I am unable to do this currently as the 'Soon-to-be' registered keeper of the car does not have insurance.

As the legal owner of the vehicle, could I call the DVLA and cancel the form to put it back in my name. (It was previously in my name.)

Comment: It may be simplest to ask the DVLA.

Comment: I totally agree, however at the time of asking i had spent 3 hours calling only to be cut off by an automated system tellinh me all lines were busy!